# 好久不见＋了＝OK or wrong? What does the "le" add?

Tags: usage, expressions, particles

"Long time no see" is 好久不见 in Mandarin. I would be inclined towards adding a 了 at the end. Would that be all right? And in that case, what does the 了 add?

Comment: Absolutely right.The difference is very very very subtle towards to no difference in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, 好久不见 and 好久不见了 are both acceptable; `了` completes the implicit meaning of "no see" as "have not seen" but can be omitted.

IMHO, the two are more or less interchangeable and it is merely a personal preference of which to use (I prefer the later as well). Nevertheless, from my experience, people usually use the former in relatively formal context. As to myself, I use `了` as a modal particle in this context, as in "Sigh/Wow/Damn, it's been long". I feel that it somehow extends or emphasizes the feeling at the moment.

On a side note, "[long time no see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_time_no_see)" is commonly believed as originated from Chinese-speaking communities in the States, i.e. it is seen as Chinglish (Please forgive my language).

Answer (score 0):

Means long time no see,

the "le" doesn' make any sense, 是语气词

语气词是表示语气的虚词，常用在句尾或句中停顿处表示种种语气。常见的语气词有：的、了、么、呢、吧、啊。语气词：附着在词语、句子末了，表示语气。

EDIT: Translation.

the "le" doesn't make any sense, it's a modal word.

Modal words are auxiliary words showing tone, often used at the end of a sentence or in the middle at a pause to show all kinds of tone. Among common tone words there are: de, le, me, ne, ba, a. Modal word: attached to the end of a word or sentence, showing tone.

Comment: Maybe you mean the "le" has no meaning but expresses some kind of tone? Otherwise all the last sentence seems disconnected from the "doesn't make any sense" to me…

Comment: did you read that? And maybe you should convert my toneless pinyin to characters + pinyin with tones...

Answer (score 0):

As othera have already pointed out, 了doesn't have explicit meaning. It's an exclamation 叹词 marking a statement. There are also exclamation words that mark excitement (啊 呀 呢 吧 啦) or question (吗 呢). Note some words can be used in a question or a statement depending o the tone you said it with… If you are not yet confused at this stage, here are two examples to play with:
我们很久没见了呢！ - long tiime no see!
我们多久没见了呀？- how long has it been?